# Replace specific characters from a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have the below pyspark dataframe.

```
column_a
name, varchar(10) country, age
name, age, decimal(15) percentage
name, varchar(12) country, age
name, age, decimal(10) percentage
```

I have to remove varchar and decimal from above dataframe irrespective of its length. Below is expected output.

```
column_a
name, country, age
name, age, percentage
name, country, age
name, age, percentage
```

How to achieve this in Pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace patterns matching `decimal()` and `varchar()` using [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html?highlight=regexp_replace).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("name, varchar(10) country, age",),
        ("name, age, decimal(15) percentage",),
        ("name, varchar(12) country, age",),
        ("name, age, decimal(10) percentage",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("column_a", ), )

df.withColumn("column_a", 
              F.regexp_replace("column_a", r"varchar\(\d*\)\s|decimal\(\d*\)\s", ""))\
  .show(truncate=False)
"""
+---------------------+
|column_a             |
+---------------------+
|name, country, age   |
|name, age, percentage|
|name, country, age   |
|name, age, percentage|
+---------------------+
"""
```